# Не получается добавить тэг на публикацию в Forum

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Сделала код с библиотекой disnake на блокирование публикации, но для добавления тэга рекомендовали его по ID добавлять, а где его найти уже не понимаю и везде гуглила. Пробовала через applied_tags, но там тоже нужен его ID. Пишу сюда с надеждой, может кто поделится как все таки добавлять tag к публикации при блокировании.
Само блокирование осуществляется так:

```
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if interaction.data["custom_id"] == 'close_ticket':
        forum_thread = interaction.message.channel
        await forum_thread.edit(locked=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для получения ID тега можно использовать функцию **available_tags**, там найти нужный тег и сохранить его ID (либо при создании сохранять, например, в базу данных):

```
    #channel = <...> - Получаем сам канал-форум
    print(channel.available_tags) #Выводим список тегов
```

Для добавления его к самой публикации получаем список уже имеющихся тегов у публикации:

```
    tags = forum_thread.applied_tags
```

И далее получаем сам тег по его ID:

```
    tag = forum_thread.parent.get_tag(ID)
```

Сохраняем в полученный список наш тег:

```
    tags.append(tag)
```

Редактируем публикацию и сохраняем новый список тегов:

```
    await forum_thread.edit(locked=False, applied_tags=tags)
```

Готовый код (сокращенный):

```
async def on_button_click(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if interaction.data["custom_id"] == 'close_ticket':
        forum_thread = interaction.message.channel
        tags = forum_thread.applied_tags.append(forum_thread.parent.get_tag(ID))
        await forum_thread.edit(locked=False, applied_tags=tags)
```